# Plotting the CDF and Quantile Functions Given the PDF

Tags: r, inverse, cdf

How would I plot the CDF and Quantile functions, in R, if I have the PDF. Currently, I have the following (but I think there must be a better way to do it):

```
## Probability Density Function
p <- function(x) {
  result <- (x^2)/9
  result[x < 0 | x > 3] <- 0
  result
}

plot(p, xlim = c(0,3), main="Probability Density Function")

## Cumulative Distribution Function
F <- function(a = 0,b){
  result <- ((b^3)/27) - ((a^3)/27)
  result[a < 0 ] <- 0
  result[b > 3] <- 1
  result
}

plot(F(,x), xlim=c(0,3), main="Cumulative Distribution Function")

## Quantile Function
Finv <- function(p) {
  3*x^(1/3)
}
```

Comment: Possibly useful: `stats::integrate`

Comment: You might also look at `library(Ryacas)` or `library(Rsympy)`

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you are after. I mean, it seems like you already know that to go from a pdf to a cdf you need to integrate. Not all functions are easily integrate-able. Your function has an analytical solution. Is this the value you want to return? Or are you just interested in numerical approximations for any pdf in general? R doesn't really understand statistics; it just has many statistical functions built in.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm wondering if there is a better way to find the CDF. I'm also looking for the quantile function.

Comment: @MrFlick @dash2 What should I put for the default value of `b`?

Comment: Better than what? Already knowing the CDF? That's pretty much the best case scenario -- when you have a nice closed from for your CDF. Base R can't help you with that. It's not great for symbolic algebra (but some of the package that @dash2 recommended could be used that way). What does "better" mean to you?

Comment: @MrFlick What should I set the default value of `b` to be?

Comment: @MrFlick Does that look right for the quantile function?

Comment: There is no default value for `b`. It depends on what region you want to calculate the area for. Maybe move `b` to be the first parameter and let `a` be optional? And as far as the quantile function goes, we're not here to check your stats homework. If you have a specific programing question or problem, please make that clear. Give sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

As @dash2 suggested, the CDF would need you to integrate the PDF, in essence needing you to find the area under the curve.

Here's a generic solution which should help. I am using a gaussian distribution as an example - you should be able to feed to it any generic function.

Note that quantiles reported are approximations only. Also, dont forget to look into the documentation for `integrate()`.

```
# CDF Function
CDF <- function(FUNC = p, plot = T, area = 0.5, LOWER = -10, UPPER = 10, SIZE = 1000){

    # Create data
    x <- seq(LOWER, UPPER, length.out = SIZE)
    y <- p(x)

    area.vec <- c()
    area.vec[1] <- 0

    for(i in 2:length(x)){
        x.vec <- x[1:i]
        y.vec <- y[1:i]

        area.vec[i] = integrate(p, lower = x[1], upper = x[i])$value
    }

    # Quantile
    quantile = x[which.min(abs(area.vec - area))]

    # Plot if requested
    if(plot == TRUE){

        # PDF
        par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
        plot(x, y, type = "l", main = "PDF", col = "indianred", lwd = 2)
        grid()

        # CDF
        plot(x, area.vec, type = "l", main = "CDF", col = "slateblue",
             xlab = "X", ylab = "CDF", lwd = 2)

        # Quantile 
        mtext(text = paste("Quantile at ", area, "=",
                           round(quantile, 3)), side = 3)
        grid()

        par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
    }
}

# Sample data
# PDF Function - Gaussian distribution
p <- function(x, SD = 1, MU = 0){
    y <- (1/(SD * sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - MU)/SD) ^ 2))
    return(y)
}

# Call to function
CDF(p, area = 0.5, LOWER = -5, UPPER = 5)
```

[image]